# Calling ofSetWindowShape() in windowResized() freezes app on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm trying to make the OF window get resized proportionally maintaining the same ratio between `width` and `height` of the window.

For example, if you created a window with `400x300` dimensions and if you stretch the width to `800`, then the height will automatically be stretched to `600` even though you only stretched the window horizontally.

Anyways, in order to implement this feature, I needed to use `ofSetWindowShape()` inside `windowResized()` listener.

I could quickly prototype this on MacOS X and it worked very well.

Here's the code:

**ofApp.h**

```
enum ScaleDir { //window scaling directions

    SCALE_DIR_HORIZONTAL,
    SCALE_DIR_VERTICAL,
};
ScaleDir scaleDir;

int windowWidth, windowHeight; //original window dimensions
float widthScaled, heightScaled; //scaled window dimensions
float windowScale; //scale amount (1.0 = original)
bool bScaleDirFixed; //is direction fixed?
```

**ofApp.cpp**

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup(){

    windowWidth = ofGetWidth();
    windowHeight = ofGetHeight();
    windowScale = 1.0f;
    widthScaled = windowWidth * windowScale;
    heightScaled = windowHeight * windowScale;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){

    if (bScaleDirFixed) {

        bScaleDirFixed = false;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){

    ofSetColor(255, 0, 0);
    ofSetCircleResolution(50);
    ofDrawEllipse(widthScaled/2, heightScaled/2, widthScaled, heightScaled); //the ellipse will be scaled as the window gets resized.
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::windowResized(int w, int h){

    if (!bScaleDirFixed) {

        int gapW = abs(widthScaled - w);
        int gapH = abs(heightScaled - h);

        if (gapW > gapH)
            scaleDir = SCALE_DIR_HORIZONTAL;
        else
            scaleDir = SCALE_DIR_VERTICAL;
        bScaleDirFixed = true;
    }
    float ratio;

    if (scaleDir == SCALE_DIR_HORIZONTAL) {

        ratio = static_cast<float>(windowHeight) / static_cast<float>(windowWidth);
        h = w * ratio;
        windowScale = static_cast<float>(w) / static_cast<float>(windowWidth);
    }
    else if (scaleDir == SCALE_DIR_VERTICAL) {

        ratio = static_cast<float>(windowWidth) / static_cast<float>(windowHeight);
        w = h * ratio;
        windowScale = static_cast<float>(h) / static_cast<float>(windowHeight);
    }
    widthScaled = windowWidth * windowScale;
    heightScaled = windowHeight * windowScale;
    ofSetWindowShape(widthScaled, heightScaled);
}
```

However, if I run the same code on Ubuntu, the app freezes as soon as I resize the window. It seems `ofSetWindowShape()` calls `windowResized()` listener and therefore it goes into an infinite loop.

> (windowResized -> ofSetWindowShape -> windowResized ->
>   ofSetWindowShape....)

How can I change the code so it can also work on Ubuntu without the problem?
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

P.S: I would also appreciate if Linux users can confirm the app freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
ofSetupOpenGL(widthScaled, heightScaled, OF_WINDOW);
```

Apparently ofSetWindowShape() should only be called during App::Setup() ... 
[see OF tutorials here](http://openframeworks.cc/learning/01_basics/how_to_set_the_dimensions_of_the_window/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but it doesn't work.
AFAIK, ofSetupOpenGL() should only be used in main.cpp file and ofSetWindowShape() can be called elsewhere than setup().

Comment: Ah. This is alway a problem with new frameworks--the documentation is slower than the implementation. I was basing my answer off this quote regarding ofSetWindowShape():
"Alternatively, you can set the window size (and position) in the setup
function of ofApp, which gets called right at the start as the app
launches"